# How can I add to the tally of a chosen phrase?

Tags: python, file, pygame, python-3.3, editing

So I want to be able to add to the tally of a certain phrase that is contained in a file. However I have no clue on where to start.

Let me explain a little more:

I have a .txt file that is called `setPhrases.txt`. This file contains this with in it:

```
What is your name?, 9
What time is dinner?, 8
Thank-You., 9
I have done all my homework., 7
Can you bring me a drink Please?, 6
Hi my name is Dave., 10
```

I am currently able to take `(n)` number of the top phrases (So the ones with the highest count) and display them in a box on the screen.
[image]

If the user chose the biggest box (In this case the one that says "Hi my name is Dave." in it) then it will be displayed in the top screen/box. As you can see below:
[image]

Once the user has decided he/she has chosen the phrase they want they will then press OK which should then recognize the phrase/phrases on screen and should add to the tally in the file by +1.

- So in this case, the `Hi my name is Dave.` tally, would go up by one and will change to 11 and will be saved to the file as:  `Hi my name is Dave., 11`, without making any changes to any of the other phrases in that file.

[Here is the full code.](http://pastebin.com/G6hpBCTj)(Sometimes it is easier to have full code.)

This is the part where it checks to see if `OK` has been pressed and then proceeds on:

```
elif textSelected == "OK":
    self.deletePanes()
    self.createPhrases()
```

This is how I open the file:

```
def get_n_nouns(self, n):

    #Returns the n most common nouns

    with open("setPhrases.txt") as in_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file)
        data = [[row[0], int(row[1])] for row in list(reader)]

    return sorted(data, key=lambda x: -x[1])[:n]
```

This is where I write in to Pane/Box:

```
def createPhrases(self):

    print("createPhrases")
    self.deletePanes()

    self.show_keyboard = False
    self.show_words = False
    self.show_phrases = True
    self.show_terminal = True

    words = self.get_n_nouns(2)
    for word, count in words:
        self.addPane("{}: {}".format(word, count), WORDS)
    self.addPane("Boxes", PHRASE)
    self.addPane("Keyboard", PHRASE)
    self.addPane("OK", PHRASE)
    self.drawPanes()
```

Any help or comments are much appreciated.

Comment: what is the csv reader?

Comment: it is from `import csv` used for file reading and writing. [Link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). I have a very basic understanding of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the data read by you csv reader in a list, so that when modified, you can create a writer and write to the file.

```
with open("setPhrases.txt") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row in file_rows:
        spamwriter.writerow(row[0],row[1])
```

You can find the correct value to increment by searching through the list to find the string that the user clicked, or store the indicies of the displayed strings.

Comment: Thank-you for your help. And I was thinking that but thought it wouldn't work but I guess i should try it first before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: yes, that and try to split a problem into parts that you can easily check if they work.